# What the words "course" and "class" are used for?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Regarding academic context, I am a little confused about the meanings of these words.

I am going to state my understanding to see if it is correct or not:

**Course meanings:**

- A university *course* like Calculus1 or Physics2.
- The *course* I've finished is a B.Sc in Computer Science.

**Class meanings:**

- Students who graduated in 2015 form the *class* of 2015.
- I didn't attend the Calculus1 *class* this afternoon.

Are the meanings above correct?

Are there other *academic* meanings for these words?

Comment: Both of those words can have various meanings, including, but not limited to, the ones that you list.  if you want a list of meanings for a word then please consult a dictionary.

Comment: I don't think *B.Sc in Computer Science* is a ***course***. OTOH, I have encountered *Calculus 101* being referred to as a ***class***, e.g. in the context of *"students enrolling into classes"*.

Comment: These terms had precise meanings long time ago, now they are used often as synonyms. See this answer and the comments for a full explanation  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33443/what-is-the-difference-between-taking-courses-classes-or-lessons?rq=1

Comment: @P.O. How do you know they ever had precise meanings? The word *class* comes from [Latin,](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=class) where it meant "any one of the six orders into which Servius Tullius divided the Roman people for the purpose of taxation;" The word *course* comes from [Latin,](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=course) where it meant "running race."

Comment: You just said it : one meant running race (which is still one of the two meaning in French for "course" the other being an errand ) and the other a social divide (which is still one of the meaning in English). How is that not precise enough for you to not be called "precise meaning" Do you want me to look up "precise meaning" in the dictionary for you?